# Automatically populate a table with time values, based on the type of event

Tags: google-sheets

I am hoping to find a way using the conditional formatting to find an easier way to have a populated registration time (F), event start time (G) and event end time (H) for each event type as shown in the picture below.  As of right now, I am placing each by hand and it would be easier to type in the "Event Type" (E) and have the F, G & H be automatically added in.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Conditional formatting typically has to do with how you format a cell (E.g. If the cell is in bold, italics, another color etc.)  What you are looking for is really changing the value of cells based on another cell.  More specifically changing current cell based on the value of a remote cell.  You can use an if condition to set your values to accomplish this.  You would put an if condition in each of the time cells you listed.

Looking at your first line as an example.  We would put this in your Event End Time cell H2.

```
=IF(F2="Business Redefined Training (Full Day)", "8:00 PM","")
```

For now I have a "" in the else part.  We will fill that in shortly.  Lets write out the condition first and then we'll put it together

```
=IF(F2="Business Redefined Training (Half Day)", "3:30 PM","")
```

Putting these together and replacing the "" in the first else we get...

```
=IF(F2="Business Redefined Training (Full Day)", "8:00 PM",IF(F2="Business Redefined Training (Half Day)", "3:30 PM",""))
```

In short this is saying in pseudo-code

```
if (cell F2 =  "Business Redefined Training (Full Day)") {
 current cell = 8:00 PM
}

else 
    if (F2="Business Redefined Training (Half Day)" {
        current cell = "3:30 PM"
    }

else{
    current cell = ""
    }
}
```

Of course if you had more conditions to add you would place another if condition started where the last double quotes are in the code here.  That represents that last else shown above.

Hope this helps.